# How to set single notification for multiple alarm manager at same time

Tags: java, android

My application requirement is User can set multiple type reminder for same time, so at that time notification is pop up along with it's sound

My code is:

```
public class ReminderService extends Service {
    int id;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(final Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        if (intent != null) {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    id = intent.getIntExtra("ID");
                    showNotification(id);
                }
            }.start();

        }
    }

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    public void showNotification(final int id) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    Notification notification = new Notification(
                            R.drawable.icon, getString(R.string.app_name),
                            System.currentTimeMillis());
                    notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                            + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.pluck_b);
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(ReminderService.this, MyClass.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    notification.setLatestEventInfo(ReminderService.this,
                            getString(R.string.app_name), message,
                            PendingIntent.getActivity(ReminderService.this, 0,
                                    i, 0));
                    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) ReminderService.this
                            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    nm.notify((int) id, notification);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Suppose user set 3 reminder for 10:30, so it will call 3 times this service, and 3 time different notification will call, so notification sound is also not proper as it create 3 different notification.

So now what have to do, I want to call single notification for these 3 different reminder using remote view, so sound will single.

But to create remote view how can I identify number of alarm at same time.

Please any one help me to identify best approaches, what I have to do in this case so notification sound would be single for different notification.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#Java).

This sets up a one-to-many relationship between classes, which allows you to notify multiple classes from one event.